# generalizing De Morgan's Laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show: $$ B - \bigcup_{a \in A}F_{a} = \bigcap_{a \in A} (B - F_{a}) $$

and show $$ B - \bigcap_{a \in A}F_{a} = \bigcup_{a \in A} (B - F_{a}) $$

I struggle with proofs.  This is what I have for the first proof, going in one direction.  If I am correct then the other direction is straight forward.

$$
\text{let  } x \in B - \bigcup_{a \in A} F_{a} 
$$
then $$ x \in B \text{ and } x\notin F_{a} \text{ for all } x \in A$$
then $$ x \in \bigcap_{a \in A}(B - F_{a}) $$

Comment: Technically this is not a duplicate: sarah is asking for feedback on her argument (and presumably for help if the argument is incorrect, but that isn’t the case).

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the explanation a bit to make the reasoning clearer, but yes, this is correct. If $x\in B\setminus\bigcup_{a\in A}F_a$, then for each $a\in A$ we have $x\in B$ and $x\notin F_a$, so $x\in B\setminus F_a$. And since this is the case for all $a\in A$, it follows that $x\in\bigcap_{a\in A}(B\setminus F_a)$.

I’d not say that the opposite inclusion is more straightforward: it’s basically just the same argument in reverse.

Comment: Is $\forall a(x \in B)$ equivalent to $\forall a \in A(x\in B)$?  That is, does null quantification work for bounded quantifiers, too?

Answer (score 0):

$$
x\in B\setminus  \bigcup_a F_a  \Longleftrightarrow\\
x\in B \mbox{ and } x\notin \bigcup_a F_a\Longleftrightarrow\\
x\in B \mbox{ and } x\notin F_a \mbox { for any }a\Longleftrightarrow\\
x\in B\setminus F_a\mbox{ for any }a\Longleftrightarrow\\
x\in\bigcap_a B\setminus F_a
$$

Comment: Can I find out what was the reason for the downvote?