# $\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)^c = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i}^c$ and $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need instruction with the following. I am not too familiar with the superscript complements when it comes to intersections and unions of sets so I am having difficulty with the following.

Let $\{ A_{i} \mid  i\in I \}$ be a collection of sets. Show that

$$ (a) \enspace\enspace\biggl(\,\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}\biggr)^c = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i}^c
$$

and

$$(b) \enspace\enspace\biggl(\,\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}\biggr)^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_{i}^c
$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: For example, did you try searching the site? (Keyword: DeMorgan)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207570/infinite-demorgan-laws **OR** http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442290/prove-that-c-left-bigcup-alpha-in-i-a-alpha-right-bigcap-alpha-in-ic **OR** http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539576/prove-x-bigcup-c-in-scrcc-bigcap-c-in-scrcx **OR** http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395760/generalizing-de-morgans-laws...

Comment: If this question did not contain a superscript complement on the left and right side of the equation, my thinking would go as far as the following, for instance; A1 intersection A2 = A1 union A2, which isn't true I believe. That's where I'm stuck, I don't know how the superscript compliment affects this question.

Comment: If superscript $^{c}$ is used then you are supposed to be working
in some 'universe' $X$. For $A\subset X$ the set $A^{c}$ denotes
the set of elements of $X$ that do not belong to $A$ and $x\in A^{c}$
means exactly that $x\in X\backslash A$. So you are asked to show
that $X\backslash\left(\cap_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)=\cup_{i\in I}X\backslash A_{i}$
and $X\backslash\left(\cup_{i\in I}A_{i}\right)=\cap_{i\in I}X\backslash A_{i}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) $\enspace\enspace\left(\bigcap_{i    \in   I}A_{i}\right)^c = (A_{1}\bigcap A_{2}\bigcap...)^c$

After performing all the intersections, then take the complement of it.

Drawing a Venn diagram will help.

(b) can be done similarly.

Finding out what De Morgan's law is will also help.

Comment: Thank you so much, the Venn Diagram helps. I came up with an initial answer that I thought was too simple but the Diagrams give me a little more confidence that I am correct. For a heavy abstract class like this, I've been told that using words is important. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Hope it helps. By the way, what you have quoted is actually called the generalized form of the De Morgan's law.

Answer (score 1):

By definition $x \in (\bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i})^{c}$ iff $x$ is not in $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i}$, but this is true iff $\exists j\in I$ such that $x$ is not in $A_{j}$, or equivalently, $x\in (A_j)^{c}$ that imply $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} (A_i)^{c}$.

For the second one:
$x \in (\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i)^{c}$ iff $x$ is not in $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, but this is true iff $x$ is not in $A_{i}$ for all $i\in I$, that is equivalent to say $x\in (A_{i})^{c}$ for all $i\in I$, that is $x\in \bigcap_{i\in I} A_{i}^c$.

I hope it's clear.